# How to implement Authentication using Riverpod in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-riverpod

I have three providers for login => email, password, login.
then I am refreshing login provider which is a future provider and will call the login API.
now I need to see if the provider returns success then I will need to navigate to next page.
But .when() is not waiting for the refreshing to finish. Its logging "loading..." in the console.

`

```
ref.watch(email.notifier).state =
                                  emails.trim().toLowerCase();
                              ref.watch(password.notifier).state = passwords;
                              final loginstate = ref.refresh(login);
                              loginstate.when(data: ((data) {
                                // log(data + "here");
                                if (data == "Success") {
                                  context.go('/home');
                                }
                              }), error: (error, stackTrace) {
                                // log(error.toString() + "here");
                              }, loading: () {
                                log("loading....");
                              });
```

`

I need to Navigate to the Home page upon successful API call.

Comment: follow up: how do I make .when() to wait for the refreshing to finish first.

Comment: You can use ref.listen to fire a function/navigation

Comment: Yes.. It works. cant believe the solution was this simple. Thank You